# How to define a nested controller to work with Rails autoloader?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, constants, autoload

Say I have two standard rails resources defined as controllers, each with their own CRUD actions (`index`, `show`, etc...)

- `EmployeesController`
- `Employees::AssignmentController`

Directory looks like -

```
app/
  controllers/
    - employees_controller.rb
    employees/
      - assignment_controller.rb
```

I'm trying to figure out how to best define the second nested controller to work with Rails autoloader.

#### Option A - Namespaced Constant

If I do -

```rb
class Employees::AssignmentController < ApplicationController
  ...
end
```

I get the following error in my app log and when running integration tests:

```rb
LoadError: Unable to autoload constant Employees::AssignmentController, expected /Users/jeeves/git/my-project/app/controllers/employees/assignment_controller.rb to define it>
```

It doesn't like the constant defined as one single namespace - `Employees::AssignmentController`

#### Option B - Nested Constant inside a module

If I do -

```rb
module Employees
  class AssignmentController < ApplicationController
  end
end
```

I actually get the same `LoadError` error as above.

#### Option C - Nested Constant inside a class

Finally, if I do -

```rb
class Employees
  class AssignmentController < ApplicationController
  end
end
```

I get `TypeError: Employees is not a class`, which makes sense since the outer `class` isn't defined. I try and fix it by adding an explicit `class` definition with an empty file

```
 app/
   controllers/
     - employees_controller.rb
+    - employees.rb
     employees/
       - assignment_controller.rb
```

```rb
class Employees
end
```

And this works. But it feels silly to have this extra dummy file hanging around in `app/controllers`, especially when it's not even a controller itself.

## Question

Is there a correct way to approach the above situation? Is Option C my only option? Am I even correctly using namespaces or should I avoid them all together?

Thanks!

Comment: One thing to pay attention to here is that you are using the singular `AssignmentController` which is fine if you are declaring a singular resource but not if the user can have many assignments and you are using `resources :assignments`.

Answer (score 1):

> Define (and reopen) namespaced classes and modules using explicit
>   nesting. Using the scope resolution operator can lead to surprising
>   constant lookups due to Ruby’s lexical scoping, which depends on the
>   module nesting at the point of definition.
>   [- The Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#namespace-definition)

An example of this suprising behavior is:

```
class Employees::AssignmentController
  def index
    @rate = Rate.find(...)
  end
end
```

You would expect Rate to be resolved as `Employees::Rate` but its actually resolved to `::Rate` since the lexical scope is `::`.

This is the preferred method:

```
module Employees
  class AssignmentController
    def index
      @rate = Rate.find(...) # resolves to Employees::Rate
    end
  end
end
```

It reopens the module and defines a new constant in the correct lexical scope.

As to alternative C - its possible since classes in Ruby are modules (check `Class.ancestors` if you don't belive me) but its not considered good form since classes should be things that can be instantiated.

The rails generators do this the "wrong" way by using the scope resolution operator but thats really just due to limitations in the file templating system.

#### Then why am I getting a load error?

I don't actually know. This is the preferred method and there is no obvious reason why its not working in this case. Double check everything. Restart spring by running `spring stop` and restart the server.